# How to pass arguments into a command being passed into bot.get_command() in a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am dabbling in the creation of a discord bot for my private discord server and I have run into an issue.

I have three functions that `load`, `unload` and `reload` extensions in the form of cogs. The creation of the `load` and `unload` commands are totally fine but I am having trouble with the `reload` command.

In the interest of not repeating code, I want to call `unload(extension)` and `load(extension` inside of the `reload(extension)` command, however, I have not yet been able to figure out how to do so.

***Here is my code:***

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from settings import BOT_TOKEN

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=(".", "!", "?", "-"))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle)
    print("Discord_Bot is ready")

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension("cogs.{0}".format(extension))

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension("cogs.{0}".format(extension))

@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    await ctx.invoke(client.get_command("unload({0}".format(extension)))
    await ctx.invoke(client.get_command("load({0})".format(extension)))

# Load Cogs on Boot
for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension("cogs.{0}".format(filename[:-3]))


client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

I also have an `example_cog.py` I use to test the functionality of the `load`, `unload` and `reload` commands. There are no commands in this file, just the basics needed to function as a cog.

***example_cog.py***

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Example_Cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Example_Cog(client))
```

When I use the bot on my private discord server and try to reload, it does not work. I have read the documentation and I cannot figure out how to pass arguments into the `bot.get_command()` function. I would vastly appreciate help on this issue.

I have tried many different ways of using the `bot.get_command()` function but none of them work. These include:

```
await ctx.invoke(client.get_command("unload {0}".format(extension)))


await ctx.invoke(client.get_command("unload({0})".format(extension)))
```

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass name of command in string type. Example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # call command without args
    await bot.get_command('examplecommand').callback()
    # call command with args
    await bot.get_command('exampleArgsCommand').callback(ctx, message)

@bot.command()
async def examplecommand():
    pass

@bot.command()
async def exampleArgsCommand(ctx, message):
    pass
```

Comment: I realise that I need to pass the name of the command as a string, but I have done that. The problem occurs when trying to input the parameters of said command.

Comment: You don't need to pass args for command. Do you want to call this command?

Comment: Yes, I want to call the unload command. However, the unload command takes in a parameter which is extension. This tells the command which extension to unload. If I do not pass the parameter, how would it know which extension to unload?

Comment: Try this way, I think it help you.