# My bot gave me a syntax error with the callback function added to bot.get_command

Tags: python, discord

how do I fix this code

```
await bot.get_command('play').callback(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, query: str)
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax:
the ^ symbol is under the colon next to ctx
then when I remove the ctx: commands.Context, the ^ goes under the star *, then when i remove the star* it goes under query: str, i think the colons are the problem but i need them there for arguments

Comment: Where did you read that?  It looks like you are mixing a function call with a function declaration.

Comment: it worked with my music command loop because it's only self, ctx in the ()
```async def _loop(ctx):
    self = self.bot = bot
    await bot.get_command('loop').callback(self, ctx)```

Comment: what i'm doing is i'm calling a command that's in a cog, from a command in the main bot.py file, with a slash command

Comment: Yes, but the difference is you are including type hints here.  You don't use type hints when CALLING a function, only when DECLARING a function.  And what is the `*` supposed to be doing?  You should show us more of the code.

Comment: also i found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62614108/how-to-pass-arguments-into-a-command-being-passed-into-bot-get-command-in-a-di

Comment: ```@slash.slash(name="play", guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def _play(ctx):
    self = self.bot = bot
    query = query.wavelink = wavelink
    await bot.get_command('play').callback(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, query: str)```

Comment: i can't show you the cog command that i'm trying to call, from bot.py because it's too long

Comment: Where do you see anything like that on the page you cited?  Have you gotten rid of the type hints yet?  I SUSPECT you just want `...callback( self, ctx, query)`, but I can't be sure.

Comment: if i add that then it says: play() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: also what are type hints?

Comment: Google "python type hints", it's too big a topic for here.  What do you think you are calling?  If `play` only wants two arguments, why are you passing three?

Comment: it needs self, ctx: commands.Context, *, query: str, because that's what's on the play command in the music.py cog for me

Comment: You're confusing the declaration of the function with calling the function.  Change it to `...callback( ctx, query )`.

Comment: i just realized something, when i do the command it doesn't input my query aka song

Comment: it does now but still gives error play() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'query'

Comment: i tried ```cmd = bot.get_command('play')
await ctx.invoke(cmd)``` but it says missing command to invoke

Comment: I was able to fix it with completely different code